# looping while extracting data from web service

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, while-loop, output

I am new in this site so sorry in advance if my question is no well structured. I am trying to consume a web service. I need to get the much information that I get while the projectId exist. I am stuck in the way to how to extract the data.

```
test.Board proxy = new eagle.Board();
        proxy.APIKeyHeaderValue = new test.APIKeyHeader();
        proxy.APIKeyHeaderValue.Value = "2b7346bc";

    string projectId = "129b2a72";

    string[] subjects = proxy.GetSubjectList(projectId);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

After this I been trying difference loops, but I have almost 300 ProjectId, and I would like to look while there`s projectId the output will be available.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? And what didn't work? Without knowing that, it'll be hard to help.

Comment: where are you showing and or doing the `difference loops` as you have put it...? please show all relevant code.. also what does the `GetSubjextList` method look like.. extracting data should not be an issue if you have consumed the webservice properly and you are assigning the string array values back from the calling method.. also I would not use a `string[]` if you are returning on projectId's then change your webmethod to return `List<string>` it's very simple to iterate over a List<T> Collection btw

Comment: there is not enough information to answer this question. for example, we have no idea what an `eagle.Board` is.  What types it has what it does.  You also don't really have a question here.  You just say what you would like to do, not what is going wrong or why you can't do it.  My answer to this question would be -- "Ok, make a loop."

Comment: Hi, you`re all right, sorry for not give all the details. the board it shows all the APIs available. I dont have the access to view what the GetSubjectList method does but I know when I mouse over in the method its shows string[] board.GetSubjectList(string projectID). so thats why i been trying to fo the follow but I am getting errors for ( int i = 0; i < subjects.Length; i++)
            {
                label1.Text += subjects[i].ToString();
            }